# Always use `-P` flag with `cd` command

Tags: command-line, bash

How can I set `-P` flag to every `cd` command?  I do that every time. There are LS flag environment variable which I could use for `ls` command so I wonder can `-P` be set as default?

Comment: Notice that this question is more suited for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), since the question is not Ubuntu specific and is about programming. (This question is [off-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: @edwin It's definitely not about programming. I'd say it's more suited to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or maybe [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the file `/home/your-username/.bashrc` and add the following line to the end:

```
alias cd='cd -P'
```

Open a new terminal, and try using `cd` to see if it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
set -o physical
```

From the `set` section in `man bash`,

> -o option-name
>   The option-name can be one of the following:
>   ...
>   physical
>   Same as -P.
>   ...
>   -P If set, the shell does not follow symbolic links when executing commands such as cd that change the current working directory. It uses the physical directory structure instead.  By default, bash follows the logical chain of directories when performing commands which change the current directory.